# How do I retrieve parse data and enter this into a string array and/or into a spinner?

Tags: android, parsing, parse-platform, android-spinner, arrays

I have a list of fruit stored in Parse. I want to conduct a parse query and a) either directly load the objects into a spinner or b) store them as a string array which the spinner will later call.

I have been able to do the former but cannot figure out how to format the spinner. The local spinner layouts are not compatible?

If I call the array to the spinner, I can format the spinner, but I don't know how to query data to a stored R.array.fruit_array.

How would I query the "fruit" and store it in

```
   `<string-array name="fruit_array">
         <item> apple </item>
         <item> orange </item>
         <item> etc. </item>
    </string-array>`
```

Is this possible or do I need to have the spinner directly query the data?

Any suggestions?

Thanks! ^_^

---- Edited ~4:40 ----

Sorry I'm a bit new at coding... let me try to clarify this a bit. I have two spinners currently, one for vegetables and one for fruit. the fruit one is stored in the cloud for each user and the vegetable one is stored within the program. Right now, the fruit one uses a ParseQueryAdapter like so

```
    `ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
          new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
            public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
             ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Fruit");
              return query;}};

         ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory);
         adapter.setTextKey("fruiteName");
         spinFruit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMenu);
         spinFruit.setAdapter(adapter);
         spinFruit.setSelection(1);
    }'
```

This retrieves the data and formats it into a spinner, but I cannot figure out how to format the spinner from here. The text is hard to read, and normal xml formatting does not seem to affect it.

I know this works to create a spinner from a local array...

```
    `private void loadLocationDropDown() {
      ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.vegetables_array, R.layout.spinnerlayout);

     // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears

       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

     // Apply the adapter to the spinner

       spinVegetables = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMenu_2);
       spinVegetables.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }`
```

I am looking to see if there is a way to create and edit R.array.fruit_array from the parsed data 
so that I don't have to change the formatting anymore of the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Create an adapter that will manage the data the spinner recieves and then set the adapter on the spinner.

```
MyData data = getData();
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(data);
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You could also figure out a way to move your important data into an array and just use the ArrayAdapter.  Without knowing what your data models look like I can't really help much more. If you could post those I can give you more insight.

Comment: Every fruit is stored in parse.com and is associated with a user, a calorie count, and a name. I am looking to retrieve the names of the fruits associated with the user and display them in a spinner. I am using ParseQuueryAdapter right now to write them directly into a spinner, but this does not seem to be the most effective or cleanest way to do this. I understand how to adapt a spinner to a format/data, but the ParseQueryAdapter seems to adapt differently than ArrayAdapter. Any insight you could provide would be appreciated! I am a bit new to coding but I posted more clarification above.